Creating bridge with bond as slave
I am on a Ubuntu 22.04.5 LTS server. I am trying to setup a virtual bridge with a bond as a slave using netplan. I am used to nmcli, and I know how to do it using nmcli, but netplan trumps nmcli. My bond has already been setup. Now I need to add a bridge to my netplan yaml file. How do I do this?

Have you checked the netplan bridge documentation? It's pretty complete and concise.

@zwets Yes, I have. No where on the entire https://netplan.readthedocs.io they show how to create the yaml file with bond being a slave to a bridge.

And it does not work when you put your bonded interface in the interface list attached to the bridge?

@zwets Correct. Does netplan support creating a virtual bridge from a slave bond? I have googled this all day. I don't think it does.

It will help if you put your current netplan configuration in your question and explain what error you are seeing when.

Example documentaiton on how to do this is detailed in Netplan Documentation How to configure a VM host with bonded network interfaces and three VLANs. Based off of that example, it shows that you can simply add the bond as an interface to the bridge.
A basic Netplan YAML file for two interfaces configured together as a bond, which is added to a bridge as an interface would be as follows:
$ cat /etc/netplan/00-bond-bridge-config.yaml
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    enps30:
      dhcp4: false
    enps80:
      dhcp4: false
  bonds:
    bond0:
      dhcp4: false
      interfaces: [enps30, enps80]
      parameters:
        mode: active-backup
        mii-monitor-interval: 100
  bridges:
    br0:
      dhcp4: true
      interfaces: [bond0]

Obviously, this was setup with DHCP IP addressing, but adjusting to define a static IP is straight forward. Simply define a static IP for the bridge as follows. Adjust your IP address and network settings accordingly.
$ cat /etc/netplan/00-bond-bridge-config.yaml
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    enps30:
      dhcp4: false
    enps80:
      dhcp4: false
  bonds:
    bond0:
      dhcp4: false
      interfaces: [enps30, enps80]
      parameters:
        mode: active-backup
        mii-monitor-interval: 100
  bridges:
    br0:
      dhcp4: false
      interfaces: [bond0]
      addresses: [192.168.1.2/24]
      routes:
        - to: default
          via: 192.168.1.1
      nameservers:
        addresses: [1.1.1.1, 8.8.8.8]
        search: []

After configuration, run sudo netplan apply to apply the configuration.
Then run ip a to see the output:
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: enp0s3: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,SLAVE,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel master bond0 state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 36:a3:66:28:36:e3 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff permaddr 08:00:27:8c:35:70
3: enp0s8: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,SLAVE,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fa_codel master bond0 state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 36:a3:66:28:36:e3 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff permaddr 08:00:27:56:6b:6b
4: bond0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,MASTER,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue master br0 state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 36:a3:66:28:36:e3 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
5: br0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 42:3b:cd:f8:dc:f1 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 10.0.3.16/24 metric 100 brd 10.0.3.255 scope global dynamic br0
       valid_1ft 86264sec preferred_lft 86264sec
    inet6 feB0::403b:cdff:fef8:dcf1/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever


Thank you for sharing the information. DHCP is not available on my LAN. I only have static. This Ubuntu host's primary function is being a QEMU/KVM host to several VMs. ProxMox was denied, and VMWare is too expensive, so this is my only option. How would this yaml file look if my bridge needs a static IP? Thanks again for all of your assistance.

Your netplan example worked! Thank you so much.
